# Is there a way to prevent Jackson from searching type info for a specific class?

Tags: java, json, jackson, subtype

I've been working on a Java project where I use the Jackson library. This is the first time I use it and I've only discovered the "JsonTypeInfo" and "JsonSubTypes" interfaces. It is very useful to work with, but I've encountered an issue.
I have a "VisibleEntity" abstract class defined in my project, and I defined its JsonTypeInfo properties so that Jackson can automatically assign Json objects to their corresponding class.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Reef.class, name = "reef"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Stream.class, name = "stream")
})
public abstract class VisibleEntity {
    protected Position position;
    protected Shape shape;

    public VisibleEntity() {}

    public VisibleEntity(Position position, Shape shape) {
        this.position = position;
        this.shape = shape;
    }
}
```

It has been working really well since but I recently added a "Checkpoint" class which I need to extend my "VisibleEntity" class. But the Json object I work with representing Checkpoints look like this.

```
{"position":{"x":4009.1264667535834,"y":319.0104166666671,"orientation":0.0},"shape":{"type":"circle","radius":100.0}}
```

So there's no "type" property therefore Jackson throws an "InvalidTypeIdException".
Knowing that the checkpoint object are assign directly to "Checkpoint" attributes and not "VisibleEntities", is there a way for me to inform Jackson that I do not need it to seach for the "type" property ? As I kind of already tell him which subtype it corresponds to.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Add it to your subtypes list..that should allow jackson to get to it

Comment: @RichardBarker Thank you for your reply. I've already tried that. But the issue is the same. He cannot find the "type" property so it doesn't work.